# Create trigger for sqlite database that prevents insert

Tags: sql, database, triggers, sqlite

I'm trying to make a trigger for a sqlite database that represents a school. I have a table called Administrators with this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Administrators(
ssn INT CHECK(ssn > 100000000),
lName CHAR(20),
fName CHAR(10),
gender CHAR(1) CHECK(gender IN('F','M')),
dob DATE,
address CHAR(100),
phone INT CHECK(phone > 1000000000),
role CHAR(20) CHECK(role IN('Principal','Vice Principal','Dean')),
PRIMARY KEY(ssn)
);
```

I want to ensure that there is only one principal. I've tried everything I can think of and I keep getting errors at various locations in the trigger. The last one I've tried says there is an error near "IF"

```
sqlite> CREATE TRIGGER onePres
   ...> BEFORE INSERT ON Administrators
   ...> BEGIN
   ...> IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Administration WHERE role = 'Principal'))
   ...> BEGIN
   ...> ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
   ...> RETURN
   ...> END;
   ...> END;
```

Could anyone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: SSNs and phone numbers have no numeric value; use strings.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

See the [trigger documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html); you can use only `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` statements inside a trigger.

To raise errors, use the `RAISE` function from inside a `SELECT`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER onePres
BEFORE INSERT ON Administrators
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.role = 'Principal'
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'There can be only one.')
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Administrators
                  WHERE role = 'Principal');
END;
```

(You also need to check `UPDATE`s.)

Answer (score -1):

An easy way is that you could have first check the database if anyone that is a principal exists, then perform necessary action

writing a trigger for such trivial task is an overkill

Comment: And then run into concurrency issues. Also, you have to remember that you have to check such condition every time you want to insert something.